# compare time stamp stored in database in java

Tags: java, sql, date, time

I am storing current time stamp in database table using now() [example- 20160807000133 ] 
And i want to compare this time stamp stored in table with current time stamp in java.

How to do that?

My main task is to check whether data stored in table is within certain time interval with respect to current time.

Comment: Please post the code of what have you tried so far

Comment: It would be easiest to do the timestamp comparison in the query itself, without passing date time variables from Java. Which DB are you using and which tables is your query targeting?

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

```
String input = "20160807000133";
DateTimeFormatter BASIC_ISO_DATETIME = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "uuuuMMddHHmmss" );  //  Make constant somewhere in your codebase.

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse ( input , BASIC_ISO_DATETIME );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | ldt: " + ldt );
```

> input: 20160807000133 | ldt: 2016-08-07T00:01:33

## Time Zone

Note that your input data makes the mistake of failing to include any information about time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such, it does *not* represent a moment on the timeline. If that data were intended for Paris that would be a different moment than if it were meant for Montréal.

If you know the context intended a certain time zone, apply a `ZoneId` before using this value in your database query.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone ( zoneId );
```

> zdt: 2016-08-07T00:01:33-04:00[America/Montreal]

## Database

If your JDBC driver complies with JDBC 4.2 or later, you should be able to directly pass/fetch the `java.time` types via `setObject` & `getObject`.

If not, fallback to converting using the new methods added to the old classes. For `java.sql.Timestamp` that means going through an `Instant`, a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of up to nanoseconds. We can extract an `Instant` object from our `ZonedDateTime`.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( zdt.toInstant() );
myPreparedStatement.setTimestamp( ts );
```

…and…

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = myResultSet.getTimestamp( 1 );
Instant instant = ts.toInstant();
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone ( zoneId );
```